# UITableview: How to implement gray cells

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am new to Xcode and iOS development. I would like to replicate the Gmail account settings screen on iOS (Settings -> Mail, Contacts, Calendars -> Gmail). See this -> [Gmail Account Settings in iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyKkn.png)

How are the gray colored cells that are interleaved between white cells implemented? Are these section header/footer? I can't seem to implement these in Xcode without having to enter a text for them. E.g. the gray cells above and below "Delete Account" have no text in them.

Are these normal cells with their color set to gray? If yes, what's the default value of this color?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Those aren't cells. That's a table view using the "grouped" style where each group of cells is a table section.

Answer (score -1):

I think the easiest way to replicate that would to have multiple sections in the table view. Then you can have section headers that are just gray. Your actual cells would be white with whatever you want in them.